# SQL server file size affection on performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have two table in database A,B

- A: summary view of my data
- B: detail view (text files has detail story)

I have 1 million record on my database 70% of the size is for Table B and 30% for Table A.

I want to know if the size of database affect the query performance response time ?
Is it beneficial to remove my Table B and store it on Disk to reduce the file size of the database to optimize the performance of my database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely size can be a factor on DB performance!  However, the size can be mitigated through the proper use of indexes, relationships and integrity.  There are a number of other things than can cause performance loss like triggers that may execute in unwanted situations.

I would say removing the table is an option but I don't think should be your first choice.  Make sure your database has used the things I mention above properly.

There are many databases that are exponentially larger than yours that perform very well.  Also, use explain plans on your queries to make sure you are using sound syntax like the proper use of joins.

I would personally start with using explain plans.  This will tell you if you are missing indexes, joins, etc. Then make the changes one at a time until you are happy with the performance.

Answer (score 0):

A million records is a tiny table in database terms. Any modern datbase should be able to handle that without breaking a sweat, even Access can easily handle that. If you are currently experiencing performance problems you likely have database design problems, poorly written queries, and/or inadequate hardware.